# How to handle @JoinColumn in your own NamingStrategy implementation?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I thought that `joinKeyColumnName()` handles `@JoinColumn`, but in reality I could not get it to work. I want to get rid of the necessity to write `name=""` in `@JoinColumn` I want the property to be used as the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the @JoinColumn annotation at all:

```
@Entity
public class PrimaryEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryEntity")
    public List<RelatedEntity> getRelatedEntities() {
        return relatedEntities;
    }

}

@Entity
public class RelatedEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    public PrimaryEntity getPrimaryEntity() {
        return primaryEntity;
    }

}
```